# Jest hangs in i18n.configure()

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I'm building a Restfull API using **Node.js** and **express** and decided to test my application using **Jest** and **Supertest**, in my App class I require some **i18n** configuration (The i18n is a library used for translations).

When running the regular express server and testing my routes manually with **Insomnia** or **Postman**, everything works fine. But when I try to create a test for the **/login** route, the test runs fine and I get the expected results, but Jest never finishes running and it says `Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting`. From what it points out it seems to the be call to `i18n.configure(...` that leaves an open handle, funny enough I've checked the method `configure` and it is not asynchronous.

Here is the console output:
[image]

Here is my App.js file:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" ? ".env.test" : ".env"
});
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

class AppController {
  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.configure();
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
  }

  async configure() {
    this.i18n = require("./config/i18n");
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.express.use(express.json());
    this.express.use(cookieParser());
    this.express.use(this.i18n.init);
  }

  routes() {
    this.express.use(require("./routes"));
  }
}

module.exports = new AppController().express;
```

The i18n config file:

```
const i18n = require("i18n");

i18n.configure({
  locales: ["pt-br", "en-us"],
  defaultLocale: "pt-br",
  cookie: "locale",
  directory: "./locales",
  autoReload: true
});
i18n.setLocale("pt-br");

module.exports = i18n;
```

The test itself:

```
const request = require("supertest");    
const app = require("../../src/app.js");

describe("Authentication", () => {

  it("should not authenticate when user does not exist", async () => {
    const response = await request(app)
      .post("/login")
      .send({
        username: "john",
        password: "123123"
      });

    expect(response.status).toBe(401);
  });
});
```

The /login route (**It is inside a login folder, that is why I'm able to declare just "/" for the route**):

```
const routes = require("express").Router();

const LoginController = require("../app/controllers/LoginController");

routes.post("/", LoginController.index);

module.exports = routes;
```

The `LoginController` with the index function:

```
const passport = require("../../app/middlewares/passport");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

class LoginController {
  async index(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate("local", { session: false }, (error, user) => {
      if (error || !user) {
        res.status(401).send(res.__(error));
      } else {
        const payload = {
          username: user.username,
          expires: Date.now() + parseInt(process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_MS)
        };

        req.login(payload, { session: false }, error => {
          if (error) {
            res.status(400).send({ error });
          }

          const token = jwt.sign(
            JSON.stringify(payload),
            process.env.APP_SECRET
          );

          res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
          res.status(200).send({ username: user.username });
        });
      }
    })(req, res);
  }
}

module.exports = new LoginController();
```

Just in case, here is the passport strategies:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
const JWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

const { User } = require("../models");

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ where: { username } });
      let passwordsMatch = false;
      if (user) {
        passwordsMatch = await user.checkPassword(password);
      }

      if (passwordsMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done("Incorrect username and/or password");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  })
);

passport.use(
  new JWTStrategy(
    {
      jwtFromRequest: req => req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1],
      secretOrKey: process.env.APP_SECRET
    },
    (jwtPayload, done) => {
      if (Date.now() > jwtPayload.expires) {
        return done("jwt expired");
      }

      return done(null, jwtPayload);
    }
  )
);

module.exports = passport;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need disable `autoReload` option when using i18n-node with jest. I think it is related to this opened [issue](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node/issues/359).

Try something like this :

```
i18n.configure({
  locales: ["pt-br", "en-us"],
  defaultLocale: "pt-br",
  cookie: "locale",
  directory: "./locales",
  autoReload: false
});
```

Or if your `NODE_ENV` variable equals **"test"** :

```
i18n.configure({
  locales: ["pt-br", "en-us"],
  defaultLocale: "pt-br",
  cookie: "locale",
  directory: "./locales",
  autoReload: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test"
});
```

It worked for me.